# Show and hide a popup on div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am working on a small website and have some `divs` arranged in the layout on the click of which I have to show a `modal window` by animation.

After it has appeared, when the user pressed `Esc`, the modal window has to close and should open again with the same effect if the button is clicked again.

Here's how my code looks like: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4d2Mx/3/)

For me, the div appears first time (not appearing in this fiddle though somehow), and on clicking on it the next time, it just makes it's display visible (the animation doesn't repeat again). It would be great if somebody could point out what I am missing here or what's wrong in the above code.

Comment: your fiddle is having Syntax error

Comment: Delete the last `});` and the fiddle will work

Comment: it seems your fiddle is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/JMU8A/1/

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        $(".modal-mask").css("display", "");
        $(".modal-popup").css({
            "display": "",
            "width": "",
            "height": "",
            "top": "",
            "left": ""
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to be working. Would it be an elegant solution though?

Comment: The animation is pretty complicated. All 4 animated CSS properties must be resetted. May be there is a better solution, but I don't see it.

Comment: @EgorNepomnyaschih : Marked as answer. `$(".modal-popup").removeAttr('style');` did the trcik for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted but here you go

```
$(function () {
    $(".bigbutton").on("click", function () {
        $(".modal-mask, .modal-popup").fadeIn();
        $(".modal-popup").animate({
            width: '80%',
            left: '10%'
        }, 'slow', function () {
            $(".modal-popup").animate({
                'height': '80%',
                    'top': '10%'
            }, 200, "swing", function () {});
        });
    });
    $(document).on("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
            $(".modal-popup").animate({
                width: '5%',
                left: '50%'
            }, 'slow', function () {
                $(".modal-mask, .modal-popup").fadeOut();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/4d2Mx/6/)

Notes to your `animate()` parameters. `Slow` already means that the duration is 200 so you don't have to pass that again.

Comment: Clicking on the button second time doesn't fire the animation animation again.